# Firebase: Let user communicate with server separately

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, server, google-cloud-firestore

I've built a ToDo App with Flutter and Firebase, but now I have the problem that every device shows the same ToDos. **So how can I let each of them communicate with the server separately**, so that every device/user can his or her own ToDos? That's my code. I also use a FloatingAciontbutton to create the ToDos.

```
String input = "";


  createTodos() {
    DocumentReference documentReference =
    Firestore.instance.collection("MyTodos").document(input);

    //Map
    Map<String, String> todos = {"todoTitle": input};

    documentReference.setData(todos).whenComplete(() {
      print("$input created");
    });
  }

  deleteTodos(item) {
    DocumentReference documentReference =
    Firestore.instance.collection("MyTodos").document(item);


    documentReference.delete().whenComplete(() {
      print("$item deleted");
    });
  }

  moveTodos(item) {
    DocumentReference documentReference =
    Firestore.instance.collection("MoveTodos").document(item);

    //Map
    Map<String, String> todos = {"todoMove": item};

    documentReference.setData(todos).whenComplete(() {
      print("$input moved");
    });
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection("MyTodos").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshots){

            if(snapshots.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();

            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshots.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshots.data.documents[index];
                  return Dismissible(
                    background: Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      alignment: Alignment(-0.9, 0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white,),
                    ),
                    secondaryBackground: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      alignment: Alignment(0.9, 0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white,),
                    ),
                    onDismissed: (direction) {
                      if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                        moveTodos(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]);
                        deleteTodos(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]);
                      } else
                      if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
                        deleteTodos(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]);
                      }
                    },
                    key: Key(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]),
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                        ),
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"] ?? "No ToDos yet!"),
                          trailing: Wrap(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.check),
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    moveTodos(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]);
                                    deleteTodos(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]);
                                  } ),
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    deleteTodos(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]);
                                  } ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey[500],
                                offset: Offset(4.0, 4.0),
                                blurRadius: 15.0,
                                spreadRadius: 1.0
                            ),
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                offset: Offset(-4.0, -4.0),
                                blurRadius: 15.0,
                                spreadRadius: 1.0
                            ),
                          ]
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a users collection:

```
users(collection) --> userId(document) -> userData
```

Then you can create a todo collection:

```
myTodos(collection) --> userId(document) --> todoData
```

So when creating, you can do the following:

```
  createTodos() async{
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    DocumentReference documentReference =
    Firestore.instance.collection("MyTodos").document(user.uid);

    //Map
    Map<String, String> todos = {"todoTitle": input};

    documentReference.setData(todos).whenComplete(() {
      print("$input created");
    });
  }
```

Using the `uid`, you can retrieve the todo of each user

Comment: Thank you. I now added that to my code, but now FirebaseUser and FirebaseAuth are underlined with red color. And how exactly does it have to look in the database?

Comment: FirebaseUser and FirebaseAuth are inside the firebase_auth flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth so you need to use that package in your app, and you can create a separate user collection as said in the answer

Comment: if you want to retrieve documents for a certain user then you can also do  `Firestore.instance.collection("MyTodos").document(user.uid)get().then((value){
      print(value.data);
    });`

Comment: Perfect! Now I got the firebase_auth package. And I now added a new collection called "users" --> document named "userID" -> field called "userdata". Is that correct? Sorry but I'm new to Firebase :)

Comment: no, document should be the id `FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser; Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(user.uid).setData({"name":"john","age:12});`

Comment: Yes but how do I get the User ID? Do I need a login? sorry...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212773/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-jan-feder).